# ng-model not working AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

For some reason AngularJS Is not working on our site.. We tested this:

register.html:

```
<form name="register_form">
    <ion-view view-title="Login" align-title="center">
        <ion-content style="background: #FFD700; background-size: cover;">

             <input type="password" ng-model= "name" required="required"/>

            <button ng-click="register_sub()"></button>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</form>
```

register.ctrl.js:

```
(function(angular) {

  'use strict';

    angular
            .module('Hive')
            .controller('registerCtrl', ["$scope", "refService","letterAvatarService", registerCtrlFunc]);

    function registerCtrlFunc($scope, refService,letterAvatarService) {

        $scope.register_sub = function()
        {
              console.log($scope.name)
        }
    }

})(angular);
```

When I click button , it logs `Undefined` for some reason. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to add a `name` attribute for `input`, I've met this before, this is how I fixed it.

Comment: @Sky try to add a name?? What

Comment: Well, it works fine when I test it..

Comment: @developer033 not here: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/hive

Comment: I don't have an acoount on this site.. can you create it in CodePen/Jsfiddle/Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine except one small mistake ie. there is space between "ng-model=" and "name"

```
         <input type="password" ng-model= "name" required="required"/>
```

try

```
         <input type="password" ng-model="name" required="required"/>
```